# iconButton on Stack Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I use an `IconButton` floating over an `image`?
I tried wrapping both with `Stack` widget. I even wrapped with `gesturedetector`, but the `IconButton` is still not clickable.

```
Stack(
   children: [  
      Container(
         width: double.infinity,
         height: size.height * 0.5,
         child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: widget._url, filterQuality: FilterQuality.low, 
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: (context, url) return CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
            ),
         ),
         Positioned(
            bottom: 17,
            right: 17,
            child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
               child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white54,
                  child: IconButton(
                     onPressed: () -> print('print'), 
                     icon: Icon(Icons.zoom_out_map_outlined))),
))])
```

I want it to look something like this:
[image]

Comment: I don't necessarily see any problem with your approach as I ran it on a DartPad and seemed. To be working alright without the `CachedNetworkImage`. One way you could solve this is by providing the image in a `DecoratedBox`.

Comment: it was `decoratedBox` before but i have a huge amount of data to be fetched so `CachedNetworkImage` is the only way too keep things as smooth as butter, but the button doesnt work on me so your saying that removing `CachedNetworkImage` would solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Due to Container's colour...click effect can't be seen...so change to material and give colour

here is what I changed.. and working well

```
Material(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Container(
                    //color: Colors.white54,
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          print('i am clicked');
                        },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.zoom_out_map_outlined)))
```

Comment: I faced this problem once...and solved with Material....mostly container's colour hide tap effect of IconButton.....and don't forget to rate my answer if it work..Thanks